# Waiting into controller until wifi enabled IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, wifi, reachability

I have a controller in my app that needs internet connection to run. I know what i have to do if device has or not internet connection before the app begins. Although i have stucked with the issue that the user must enable internet connection into app. I have a method that checks if there is internet connection and if not it shows an alert view. I want to retain to this view controller until internet enabled. Here is the code of my function that is not working. Any advice are welcome.

```
- (void) checkIfInternetEnabled{

    Reachability *hostReach = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName: @"www.apple.com"] ;

    NetworkStatus netStatus = [hostReach currentReachabilityStatus];

    if (netStatus != ReachableViaWiFi){

        NSLog(@"oooaoaoaolaoeworolaowoeoal");

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Warning" message:@"You must enable wi-fi the first time that you use the application for complete installation " delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

        [alert show];

        netStatus = [hostReach currentReachabilityStatus];

        while(netStatus!= ReachableViaWiFi){

            [alert show];

            netStatus = [hostReach currentReachabilityStatus];

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should listen to the notifications that reachability class sends about network status changes (you should use reachability 2.x):

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(reachabilityChanged:)
                                             name:kReachabilityChangedNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

Comment: Can u explain me please in which point of the code i have to add this?

Comment: In your viewDidLoad method

Comment: Nikos can you post please an example of a viewDidLoad method that is waiting until wifi enabled?

Comment: Hi Hoya, try to search for Reachability, you can easily find many related articles, this class will let you know when network connection is changed via a delegate method.

Comment: I have done many tries but none of them seems to work. Does simulator recognise reachability changes?

Comment: Not sure. You should better try it on a real device.

Comment: I have these lines in my viewDidLoad: `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reachabilityDidChange:) name:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil];
    
    [hostReach startNotifier];
` and my method for connection changes is the below: `- (void)reachabilityDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification {
    Reachability *reachability = (Reachability *)[notification object];
    if ([reachability currentReachabilityStatus]) {
        NSLog(@"Reachable");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Unreachable");
    }
}` but it does not works. Is it my fault?

Comment: Follow this tutorial: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-detecting-network-changes-with-reachability/